# Python numpy zeros array being assigned 1 for every value when only one index is updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, svm

The following is my code:

```
amount_features = X.shape[1]

best_features = np.zeros((amount_features,), dtype=int)
best_accuracy = 0
best_accuracy_index = 0

def find_best_features(best_features, best_accuracy):

    for i in range(amount_features):
        trial_features = best_features
        trial_features[i] = 1
        svc = SVC(C = 10, gamma = .1) 
        svc.fit(X_train[:,trial_features==1],y_train)
        y_pred = svc.predict(X_test[:,trial_features==1])
        accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
        if (accuracy > best_accuracy):
            best_accuracy = accuracy
            best_accuracy_index = i

    print(best_accuracy_index)
    best_features[best_accuracy_index] = 1

    return best_features, best_accuracy

bf, ba = find_best_features(best_features, best_accuracy)

print(bf, ba)
```

And this is my output:

```
25
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 0.865853658537
```

And my expected output:

```
25
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0] 0.865853658537
```

I am trying to update the zeros array with the index that gives the highest accuracy. As you see it should be index 25, and I follow that by assigning the 25 index for my array equal to 1. However, when I print the array it shows every index has been updated to 1.

Not sure what is the mishap. Thanks for spending your limited time on Earth to help me.

Comment: `trial_features = best_features` copies only the reference to the created numpy array, so changes to `trial_features` also happen to `best_features`

Comment: Very interesting, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `trial_features = best_features` to `trial_features = numpy.copy(best_features)`. Reasoning behind the change is already given by @Michael Butscher.